# Sequence number start from set value

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sequence

i would like to add a sequence nr from a set value.

is this **output** possible?

```
p_id    date          days     OUTPUT(what i want)
3385    2012-02-02    556      0
3385    2012-02-03     1       1
3385    2012-09-24     234     0
3385    2012-09-25     1       1
3385    2013-11-12     413     0
3385    2013-11-13     1       1
3385    2013-11-14     1       2
3385    2013-11-15     1       3
3385    2014-09-09     298     0
3385    2014-09-10     1       1
3385    2014-09-11     1       2
3385    2015-11-11     426     0
3385    2015-11-12     1       1
3385    2015-11-13     1       2
3385    2015-11-14     1       3
3385    2015-11-15     1       4
3385    2015-11-16     1       5
3385    2015-11-17     1       6
3385    2015-11-18     1       7
3385    2015-11-19     1       8
3385    2015-11-20     1       9
```

The days column counts days from the row abow it.

if the days value is greater the 5 then start a new "0" and then a new sequence number.

Comment: I suppose you're looking for something like `Row_number()  OVER(             partition`.

Comment: how would i use that? on a new set of numbers if the days are greater then 5?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT p_id, [date], days,
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY p_id, grp 
                          ORDER BY [date]) - 1 AS [OUTPUT]
FROM (
  SELECT p_id, [date], days, 
         SUM(IIF(days > 5, 1, 0)) OVER (PARTITION BY p_id
                                        ORDER BY [date]) AS grp
  FROM mytable ) AS t
```

**Explanation:**

The inner query uses `SUM() OVER()` to produce the following output:

```
p_id    date        days    grp
===============================
3385    2012-02-02  556     1
3385    2012-02-03  1       1
3385    2012-09-24  234     2
3385    2012-09-25  1       2
3385    2013-11-12  413     3
3385    2013-11-13  1       3
3385    2013-11-14  1       3
3385    2013-11-15  1       3
3385    2014-09-09  298     4
3385    2014-09-10  1       4
3385    2014-09-11  1       4
3385    2015-11-11  426     5
3385    2015-11-12  1       5
3385    2015-11-13  1       5
3385    2015-11-14  1       5
3385    2015-11-15  1       5
3385    2015-11-16  1       5
3385    2015-11-17  1       5
3385    2015-11-18  1       5
3385    2015-11-19  1       5
3385    2015-11-20  1       5
```

`grp` field is essentially the *running total* of *'greater than 5'* occurrences. Using this field in an outer query we can easily produce the required enumeration with `ROW_NUMBER` window function.

Comment: please have a look at my updated question, for some reason it goes wrong at one point?

Comment: @Nils Can you setup an [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) with some sample data demonstrating the issue? Or at least update your question including data that reproduce the issue.

Comment: i really do not understand what you mean "Or at least update your question including data that reproduce the issue" but i will try to update my question with my error

Comment: @Nils Using the sample data provided my query produces the expected result (I've already tested that). Can you provide some data where my query produces the result that you mention?

Comment: i have updated my question with some table for data hope that is enough?

Comment: @Nils I've tested my query with the new sample data provided and it run ok. Have you included *all* of the data?

Comment: I tested this solution and got an exact match to wanted output column

Comment: i have now added all the data

Comment: @Nils I've just tested and it executes ok on my end. Last row I get is 
`(3385, '2016-01-21 ', 1, 70)`.

Comment: yes sorry this do work. i forgott to add the output column for some reason (?) Thank you.

I will mark you answer this was really heplfull. Now im going to try to understand what you did :)